# Phalcon - How to call a model in another controller? "Error: Class not found"

Tags: php, frameworks, phalcon

How to call a model in another controller?
I explain myself, I created a controller and I try to call another model in this controller, but I have the error "Error: Class not found".

You can see the code of my controller "Adserver" trying to call the model "Zone"

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Zone as Zone;


class AdserveurController extends ControllerBase
{

    public function indexAction()
    {

        $id_zone= 1;
        
        $zone = Zone::findFirstByid_zone($id_zone);

        if(!zone){
            $this->flashSession->error('erreur id');
            return $this->response->redirect();
        }
        print_r ($id_zone);

        $zone = Zone::findFirst($hauteur);

        if(!zone){
            $this->fashSession->error('erreur hauteur');
            return $this->response->redirect();
        }
        
        $zone = Zone::findFirst($largeur);

        if(!zone){
            $this->fashSession->error('erreur hauteur');
            return $this->response->redirect();
        }
       
    }
   
    


  

}
```

On top of my controller, I tried the "use Phalcon\Mvc\Model"  and the error persists.

My phalco version is 4.0

Could someone help me on how to call two models in a separate controller?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share your loader? Also, tables and field names in Phalcon are a bit peculiar: the field `id_zone` must be read as Zone::findFirstByIdZone($id_zone), as described in the docs: https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/db-models#findfirstby

Comment: Hello, my Loader is like: $loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();

/**
 * We're a registering a set of directories taken from the configuration file
 */

$loader->registerDirs(
    [
        'MyApp\Controllers'=>$config->application->controllersDir,
        'MyApp\Models'=>$config->application->modelsDir
    ]
)->register();

Comment: hi there! Then probably is an issue with the namespaces. It's always  handier to assign a namespace to the models and register them like that. Then you would use, in example, `use MyApp\Models\{Zone1, Zone2, ...}`. You can use infinite models in one function without issues. `Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Zone` is not correct and that is why is not loading.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner. So I should change the namespace in the Controller or in the Model?

Comment: I'll write a longer reply as an answer, give me a few minutes.

Comment: I tested using on the top "use MyApp\Models\Zone;" in Controller and the error persists.

Comment: `MyApp\Models\Zone` is an example (see answer below). Please share the structure of your project to suggest the proper namespace for your models.

Comment: My Model Zone: namespace MyApp\Models; use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;class Zone extends Model
{ public $id_zone;  public $id_editeur;public $id_site; public $hauteur; public $largeur; public function initialize()
    {
        $this->setSchema("phalcon");
        $this->setSource("zone");
        $this->belongsTo('id_editeur', '\Editeur', 'id_editeur', ['alias' => 'Editeur']);
        $this->belongsTo('id_site', '\Site', 'id_site', ['alias' => 'Site']);
    }   public static function find($parameters = null): \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\ResultsetInterface {return parent::find($parameters);
    }

Comment: Normally at the top of my Model I only have "class Zone extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model", but when I use
"namespace MyApp\Models; use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;" my Zone view doesn't work.

Comment: If you don't mind, let's continue in the comments section of the answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75056584/12278292  Please share your app file structure and the new loader adding namespaces. Also, the ` find` function is redundant: it's pre-built in every Phalcon model.

Comment: Remember adding in your view `use MyApp\Models\Zone`. You will have to do this in every controller where you want to call the Zone model.

Answer (score 0):

I call multiple models from withing various controllers all the time and don't have to declare "use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Zone as Zone;" at the top.

How is your Zone model file defined?

Answer (score 0):

if *other_model* has relation with Zone (defined in model) then :

Zone->*other_model*->field;

else in head of file

"use Phalcon\Mvc\Model*other_model*;

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the namespace in your model, like:

```
// app/models/Zone.php

<?php

namespace MyApp\Models;

use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;

class Zone extends Model
{
     public function initialize()
     {
          $this->setSource('zone');
     }
 }
```

Then in your loader:

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Loader;

$loader->registerNamespaces(
   [
      'MyApp\Models' => 'app/models'
   ]
);

$loader->register();
```

Then in your controller:

```
<?php

use MyApp\Models\Zone;
```

Your current `indexAction` should work, but beware of what I commented to you regarding fields with underscores:

```
$zone = Zone::findFirstByid_zone($id_zone); //won't work

$zone = Zone::findFirstByIdZone($id_zone);  //works
```

Since you commented that you are a beginner, I would recommend you to review the MVC examples for Phalcon projects: https://github.com/phalcon/mvc  So you get acquainted with namespaces in your app.

Also, if you are working on a large application, it's better that you register namespaces than directories for performance reasons, as detailed in the Docs: https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/loader

Ps. Reviewing `indexAction` there are some parameters that are not defined, like `$hauteur` and `$largeur`. Since `$zone` still is not working, these issues are still not visible --but they'll show up after `zone` is working.